# STUFF does not exist

Tags: sql, update

Нужно в базе данных заменить первую цифру 8 в номерах телефонов на 7

899999999 -> 799999999

Пробовал так:

```
UPDATE team_users 
SET team_user_phone=STUFF(team_user_phone,1,1,'7')
WHERE team_user_phone LIKE '8%';
```

Выдаёт ошибку

```
#1305 - FUNCTION f0106330_virtual.STUFF does not exist
```

Как победить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно изменить ваш запрос таким образом:

```sql
UPDATE team_users 
  SET team_user_phone = '7'+ SUBSTR(team_user_phone, 2)
  WHERE team_user_phone LIKE '8%';
```